# Floating list has an indent and I don't understand why

Tags: html, css, css-float

At some point my floating link list has ended up with an indent, causing the last link to go onto a new line (or over the side of the `div` if I set a width for the `ul`).

I literally don't know where to start looking for this problem. I'm just going to go ahead and link to the website. Here's the HTML for that section:

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul id="navLinks">
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>


    <li><a href="alston.html">Alston</a></li>


    <li><a href="booking.html">Booking</a></li>

    <li><a href="photos.html" class="lastLink">Photos</a></li>


</ul>
</div>
```

And here is what I *believe* is the only CSS affecting it:

```
#navigation {
   position: relative;
   //width: 210px;
   //height: 600px;
   margin: 2px 0;
   font-size: 90%;
   font-weight: normal;
   clear:both;
   overflow:hidden;
}

//NAVIGATION BAR STUFF
#navLinks {
   list-style-type:none;
   //display:inline;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   width: 100%;
   padding:0;
   text-align:center;
   text-decoration: none;
   overflow:hidden;
}

ul#booking {
color:rgb(84, 154, 14);
}

ul#navlinks {
   text-algin: center;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

ul#navLinks li { display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
   line-height: 150%;
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   background-color: #fff; }

ul#navLinks li a
{
float: left;
text-align:center;
background-color: #ADF16A;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
border-left: 0px;
border-top: 0;
border-bottom: 0;
border-right: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #7AE015;
width:161px;
padding:3px 0px;
}

ul#navLinks a:hover
{
   background-color: #CC7A00;
}


ul#navLinks .lastLink{
    border:0;
}
//ul#navLinks a 
//END OF NAVIGATION BAR STUFF
```

The entire CSS is [here](http://www.wildgoosecottage.com/style1.css)

Thanks!

Comment: You're using invalid comments in your CSS. Only `/* */` is allowed.

Comment: Didn't know that. Firefox seems to treat // as a comment but I'll be more careful in future because yeah, standards are important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#navLinks` has some left padding thrown in by browser default (in my cas, `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;`). If you define `padding-left: 0;`, that will be overridden.

You did cover this base in Line 195 of your `style1.css`, which has `ul#navlinks {` but that needs to be `ul#navLinks {`.

Make sure you're spell-checking your `text-align`s, and capitalizing classes and IDs in your CSS file when they're capitalized in your CSS file.

Comment: Damn it was just a typo. I had noticed the "algin" but the CSS is cached on the server and takes a while to change. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you add a css reset file to your site it should fix your problem, which is related to padding/margin on your UL.

A css reset file, amonst many other things, sets the padding and margin on all elements to zero - allowing you the freedom to style everything exactly as required.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Interesting, will have a go with that! Thanks